# PHP: file_get_contents turn & to &amp;

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

After searching alot and followed most of the posts, i still couldn't resolve my problem.

Problem: file_get_contents turn & to &amp.

This is my code:

```
<?php

include 'paths.php';

session_start();
echo file_get_contents($solr_path.'select?q='.urlencode($_SESSION['super']).'&df=dict_word&wt=json&indent=true');
?>
```

I checked the url, its working when i change &amp with &. I've tried urlencode, htmlspecialchars_decode() and http_build_query() but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what is the value of `$_SESSION['super']` ?

Comment: It's better to use cURL call, as the parameters are encoded automatically. You don't have to worry about encoding.

Comment: Can you provide an example related to my case.

Comment: After some checkings, I found that `urlencode()` works for Urdu language words. Also, the function changes `&` to `%26`. Therefore, your `file_get_contents()` should work.

Comment: The problem is probably on your target URL instead. Does the target URL decode the parameters accordingly?

Comment: Well i check in another pc webserver the file_get_contents and curl is working properly means they are getting the data from the given url and not changing '&' with &amp. But in my pc it's not working. What could be the problem.

Comment: Are the PHP versions different? Hard to know if we don't know the difference of config of both machines.

Comment: Both are PHP Version 5.4.16

Comment: Where are these `&` being changed to `&amp;` - between the URL parameters in the URL itself? ie. `&df` becomes `&amp;df`, etc? Or in the URL parameter value `q` ie. the value of `$_SESSION['super']`? Are you suggesting that `file_get_contents()` itself appears to be changing all the `&` to `&amp;` in the URL before making the request - so the request fails?